# Google Sheets count occurance of words

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column in my spreadsheet that is a list of names and i want to count how often a name appears in that list.. i searched a lot and found out that I should usw "=COUNTIF(A:A,"John Doe"), but that gives me parsing errors ..

Basically, I have a list like this:

```
John Doe
Jane Doe
Jane Doe
John Doe
John Doe
John Doe
Jane Doe
```

And I need to count, how often the names appears in that list, so the result would be

```
John Doe | 4 
Jane Doe | 3
```

Answer (score 3):

I am so stupid :D

=COUNTIF(A:A; "John Doe") with a ";" works fine.. I always used "," to seperate..

Comment: The separator is , or ; depending on the locale of your spreadsheet, set in File > Spreadsheet Settings.